# Spring cloud configurable discovery client implementation

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

We currently use Eureka (and Ribbon) as our discovery mechanism for our Spring Cloud microservices by using the `@EnableDiscoveryClient` and having the

```
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon
```

dependencies. With the release of Spring Cloud Greenwich we are looking at moving to Kubernetes and using Kubernetes discovery (with Ribbon) instead. Ie we would keep the `@EnableDiscoveryClient`
and have the

```
spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes
spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon
```

dependencies instead as needed.

To enable initial testing of our microservices in the Kubernetes environment without having to branch all our projects and alter the dependencies, is there a way to include both sets of dependencies and switch between the implementations with configuration? Ie initally we would have eureka as the default and be able to override this to Kubernetes with config properties?

Possibly some variation of spring.autoconfigure.exclude might do this?

Comment: Yes, excluding auto configuration. I think there is also `eureka.client.enabled`

Comment: @spencergibb can you write an example?